Vercel - Supabase GET Request
I have SUPABASE database with Vercel Next.js project data is like not fetching or something
I set from supabase env. file with supabase_url and supabase_key of course set it up into Vercel too but when i want to fetch data in Production nothing is updating and the data is the same when i pushed them to the Vercel - when i add some rows into database and check it on Localhost:3000 everything is fine just the production fetching old data like its not gettin it from the database but the fetch request is always 200.
I tried many times copy the URL or KEY from supabase i thought its the env. variables doin problem but probably no. Also i disable RLS on supabase to dont have any security on the table.
